# Rings of fractions

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, localization

If $R$ is a ring, $I$ is an ideal of $R$ such that $I\ne R$, and $S$ a multiplicatively closed set of $R$, and we have that this property is true, $$\frac{a}{s} \in S^{-1}I \implies a\in I$$
Can we prove that $S\cap I= \varnothing$ ??

If yes, how is it done?
Any help is appreciated...

Comment: I think this question doesn't make much sense?

Comment: Somethings definitely wrong here; for instance, $I $ can be all of $R $.

Comment: Will it make sense if we claimed that $I \ne R$ ?

Comment: I assume you meant the null set by $\phi$, so I've edited.

Comment: Yes Thanks @jgon

Comment: The answer to your question is yes if you assume $I\ne R$. Nonetheless, this question is lacking context. What have you tried? Have you thought about what happens if $S\cap I\ne \varnothing$?

Comment: Yes @jgon I  tried but I reached nowhere, I tried to relate things with each other like $\frac{a}{s}\in S^{-1}I \implies \frac{a}{s}=\frac{b}{t};  b \in I, t\in S$ but I have no idea in mind to start with...

Comment: **Context** OP's [closely related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3160749/242) a few days agao.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $s\in S\cap I$. Then
$$
\frac{1}{1}=\frac{s}{s}\in S^{-1}I
$$
and therefore $S^{-1}I=S^{-1}R$. It follows that $I=R$, because for every $a\in R$, we have $a/s\in S^{-1}I$, so $a\in I$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $I \ne R \implies S^{-1}I \ne S^{-1}R$

Assume that $S \cap I \ne \varnothing \implies \exists s \in S \cap I$

But $1_{S^{-1}R}=\dfrac{1_R}{1_R}=\dfrac{s}{s} \in S^{-1}I$

$\implies S^{-1}I=S^{-1}R$ #contradiction.

Thus, $S \cap I=\varnothing$

Is my proof correct?

Comment: $S^{-1}I=S^{-1}R$ is not a contradiction! The contradiction comes from $\dfrac{1}{1}\in S^{-1}I\implies 1\in I\implies I=R$.

Comment: You are right, and I figured out that my first implication $I \ne R \implies S^{-1}I \ne S^{-1}R$ is wrong